# How to debug an Archived react-native build on ios

Tags: debugging, react-native

I have an archive build of a react-native project that is crashing. The problem does not present itself with the device tethered running through xCode. It's only occurring when the build is archived and the javascript code is bundled into the ios app. Is there an easy way to see console.log() statements in an archived build?

Comment: did you got any success?